# Restlet- Beginner Stuff for Client Side - Path, Accept Header, QueryParam

Tags: java, rest, jersey, restlet

Before I started with Restlet I already wrote a Jersey client. It was very intutiv - it seems like Restlet isnt. There is not much documentation and I can't solve the easiest problems.

Where I am:

```
    service = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8080/com-project-core/rest");
    service.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "admin", "geheima");
```

What I get from documentation:

```
 String myString = service.get(String.class);
```

or wrapping up a Resource:

```
 ConnectedResourceIF connectedResource = service.wrap(ConnectedResourceIF.class);
```

Thats working. But what about:

A. When I want to change my service path? In Jersey it was intuitiv like

```
 service.path("foo").path("bar")
```

for

```
http://localhost:8080/com-project-core/rest/foo/bar
```

B. I want to set a acceptHeader. In jersey it was like

```
   service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

C. I want to set query parameters. In jersey:

```
   service.queryParam("1","foo").queryParam("2","bar")
```

Sorry, hope someone can solve this beginner problems. I cant find somethign in the restlet documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For A:

> service.getChild("/foo/bar", ConnectedResourceIF.class);

For B (need a recent 2.1 RCx version):

> service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

For C (need a recent 2.1 RCx version):

> service.setQueryValue("1","foo");
>
> service.setQueryValue("2","bar");

The best place to look for such things is the Javadocs, because those API changes are pretty recent:
http://www.restlet.org/documentation/snapshot/jee/api/org/restlet/resource/ClientResource.html

We are working on a new in-depth tutorial for next 2.2 version. First finishing "Restlet in Action" book :)

Comment: Thanks for your supportive help. However it seems that I have to use version 2.1 for better client support.